# Problem with converting pointer to function from class to usual pointer

Tags: c++, callback

I don't understand what the problem is.

Field.h:

```
class Field : public Snake
{
private:
    bool checkCoord(int x, int y){...};
};
```

Snake.h:

```
class Snake
{
protected:
    void add_unit(bool (*)(int, int));
};
```

and when i try to use them:

```
Snake::add_unit(&checkCoord);
```

compiler shows this error:

```
field.cpp:26:29: error: cannot convert 'bool (Field::*)(int, int)' to 'bool (*)(int, int)'
   26 |             Snake::add_unit(&checkCoord);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                             |
      |                             bool (Field::*)(int, int)
```

Comment: Also see https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#memfnptr-vs-fnptr

Comment: `addUnit` expects a pointer to function taking two `int` and returning `bool`. You're giving it a pointer to *member-function* taking two `int` and returning `bool`. They're not synonymous. One of these has to change.

Answer (score 0):

The checkCoord() function is nonstatic, i.e., it requires that "this" is a Field.  Therefore it is incompatible with the parameter of add_unit.  If you don't reference any members of Field in checkCoord(), try:

```
private:
    static bool checkCoord(int x, int y){...};
```